# Popup window with static HTML page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am developing an application in Angular 5 and I wanted to open my 'help' page in a popup using something like 'window.open' so user can drag it around multiple screens, etc...

I created an URL like 'localhost:4200/help' and open it with window.open.
The problem is that when I use window.open it creates another instance of my application and it takes some time to load modules, etc...

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to serve a static HTML page or maybe a kind of component inside angular to pass it to window.open so when I click a button it opens instantly.

Comment: Yes, you will want to put it in the "assets" folder. Then, you can refer to it by its name (eg: "assets/static/help.html")

Comment: Yes! you can achieve that using Window class in angular

Comment: @Brian nice, so if I need to make a request to build it I need to use vanilla javascript ou can I access my service inside this html page?

Comment: If you need to communicate between the spawned window and its parent, you can use window.postMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: @Brian got it, thanks. I will try to do that. If I have some trouble I come back here. rsrs thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> it creates another instance of my application and it takes some time to load modules,

A new window is a new page. What you serve on it is your choice however. You can serve an angular app (which will take its time to run JS) or some static html that you have deployed at a url. Its your choice.